# How to solve this trigonometric equation

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

The equation

```
Sin[9 x - Pi/3] == Sin[7 x - Pi/3]
```

can solved by hand

```
Reduce[9 x - Pi/3 == 7 x - Pi/3 + k 2 Pi, x]
```

> x == k [Pi]

and

```
Reduce[9 x - Pi/3 == Pi - (7 x - Pi/3) + k 2 Pi, x]
```

> x == (5 [Pi])/48 + (k [Pi])/8

I tried solve it by *Mathematica*

```
Reduce[Sin[9 x - Pi/3] == Sin[7 x - Pi/3] , x, Reals]
```

I have not yet got the above solutions. How can I solve it?

Comment: Which version of MMA are you using? I get a complete solution with mma12....$c_1\in \mathbb{Z}\land x=2 \pi  c_1+\pi$ plus a list of roots, and when using `Solve[]` a list of conditional expressions...

Comment: @morbo Thank you very much. `Solve` is better than `Reduce` in this case.

Comment: I get a complete solution with `Reduce`. (V12)